# How to show my own products only Magento

Tags: magento, admin, roles, editing, product

I had set up a "Store Owner" role in Magento. Users with that role will be able to add/edit/delete products only.

What I need is some one to tell me how can I limit these users to see only their products in the list when they go to Catalog -> Manage Products ?

I want to achieve this with code editing if possible.

Also note that all users are using the same store.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an "out of the box" feature in Magento Community Edition (or Enterprise), so you'll need to write some code to make this work.

In general terms you'll want to:

1. Add a (hidden?) attribute to the product to store the User Id of the product "owner".
2. Write an event observer for `catalog_product_save_before` which assigns the current user's User Id field to the new product owner attribute.
3. Rewrite the `_prepareCollection` or `_addColumnFilterToCollection` methods of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` to add the product_owner attribute to the collection and filter it to just the current user.

That will ensure that the only products that appear in the grid for a given user are the products they own.  However, I would also implement an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit` and `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_save` events to check the product owner value on products before they're edited/saved to make sure the user hasn't tried to edit a product that doesn't appear on the grid.

If you need any further assistance with adding attributes, setting up block rewrites, or creating event observers, I'm sure those questions have already been answered on SO, this question is a bit too broad to answer at that level of detail.